# check boolean expression in dataframe Rcpp (C++)

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, rules

I have a dataframe `dat` with data and a vector `rule` with logical rules

```
set.seed(124)
ro <- round(runif(n = 30,1,10),2)
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(data =ro,ncol = 3)) ; colnames(dat) <- paste0("x" ,1:ncol(dat))
rule <- c("x1 > 5 & x2/2 > 2"  ,  "x1 > x2*2"  ,  "x3!=4")
```

I need to check if the expression is true

```
id <- 2
 for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
   cr <- with(data = dat[i,] , expr = eval(parse(text = rule[id])))
   print(cr)
 }
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] TRUE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] TRUE
```

How to do this with `Rcpp` ?

Comment: That's not a well-posed question. You rely on `eval()` here: where / how would Rcpp have something equivalent?  It can't so you'd end up calling `eval()` in R from C++.  There are of course a myriad of ways to build a decision tree from a description.  But they are not one-liners.  (Also, for what it is worth, even with your seed, I get `with(dat, x1 > 5 & x2/2 > 2 & x1 > x2*2 & x3 != 4)` returning all `FALSE`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering, Look carefully, there are three rules, not one

Comment: Whether it's one rule out of three, or one composed of three, your problem is more deep-seated as I tried to expain. `eval()` very much needs an interpreter. Rcpp does not ship one, it can only call R _or compile code using directly compilable expressions_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things worth stressing here are

- you do not need a low over all rows as R is vectorized, and that already fast
- you can sweep the rules over your data and return a result matrix

Both of those are a one-liner:

```
> res <- do.call(cbind, lapply(rule, \(r) with(dat, eval(parse(text=r)))))
> res
       [,1]  [,2] [,3]
 [1,] FALSE FALSE TRUE
 [2,] FALSE FALSE TRUE
 [3,]  TRUE FALSE TRUE
 [4,] FALSE FALSE TRUE
 [5,] FALSE FALSE TRUE
 [6,] FALSE  TRUE TRUE
 [7,]  TRUE FALSE TRUE
 [8,]  TRUE FALSE TRUE
 [9,]  TRUE FALSE TRUE
[10,] FALSE  TRUE TRUE
>
```

(I used the R 4.1.* anonymous function there, you can relace `\(r)` with the standard `function(r)` as well.)

As this is already vectorised it will be faster than your per-row call, and even if you did it with Rcpp if would not be (much) faster than already vectorised code.